# Does Google App Engine support log sampling?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

By log sampling I mean that not all the logs are saved to Stackdriver but just a sample of them. Useful for high traffic applications.

I've searched but the only mention I see is [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/tracing#disabling_trace_sampling) in the context of App Engine Flex and OpenAPI.

There is also an option to sample logs at query time [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions#sample).

Log sampling is also mentioned as an option for Trace clients [here](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#reduce_your_trace_usage) but that doesn't seem applicable to App Engine.

Comment: if you are concerned with the volume, don't be. stackdriver logs is made for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackdriver does not have built in support for sampling logs but you can specify a log exclusion filter which will allow you to remove log entries based on a criteria.

If you choose to exclude everything and specify a sampling criteria I think you can achieve this:

[image: Exclusion Criteria]

The link below explains this in a bit more detail:

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/exclusions